# Knockout JS - if data binding inside foreach data binding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am trying to get a if condition inside a foreach binding but it is not working for me. Below is the code that I tried:

**View**

```
<div class="section-wrap break" id="ServicePlan_PrioritySection" data-bind="foreach:applicationView.ViewModel.AllPersonal">
            <div data-bind="if:IsValidServicePlan(applicationView.ViewModel.AllPersonal[0], false)">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/ServicePlan/_Priority1.cshtml");}
        </div>
```

**The Function that Is called**

```
function IsValidServicePlan(priority, checkDetailFlag) {
var upActivityTempArr = ko.observableArray([]);

ko.utils.arrayForEach(priority.UpcomingActivities(), function (activity) {
    if (activity != undefined)
        if (!IsValidActivity(activity))
            upActivityTempArr.push(activity); // push valid Activity
});
ko.utils.arrayForEach(upActivityTempArr(), function (activity) {
    if (activity != undefined)
        priority.UpcomingActivities.remove(activity); // push valid Activity
});

if (hasValue(priority.Detail())
|| hasValue(priority.TimeFrames())
|| hasValue(priority.Feedback.SatisfactionLevel()) && priority.Feedback.SatisfactionLevel() != Satisfaction_Level
|| hasValue(priority.Feedback.FeedbackComment()) && priority.Feedback.FeedbackComment() != "Add Comment"
    ) {
    return true;
}}
```

When The function is called from the if condition, the priority parameter comes out as undefined. My requirement is that when the foreach loop is run, it will check and render the partial view only for those whose value is not empty. How will i resolve this to get this resolved?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: try this `IsValidServicePlan.bind($data,applicationView.ViewModel.AllPersonal[0], false)` hope that helps

Comment: alternatively you can use `function(){IsValidServicePlan(applicationView.ViewModel.AllPersonal[0], false)}` cheers

Comment: Its not working when I use the above statement.

Comment: both statements not working you mean to say ? if thats the case can you check are you really getting data in `applicationView.ViewModel.AllPersonal[0]`

Comment: yes i am getting the data: however, I used the code as 

<div class="section-wrap break" id="ServicePlan_PrioritySection" data-bind="foreach:applicationView.ViewModel.AllPersonal">
                <div data-bind="if:IsValidServicePlan.bind($data,applicationView.ViewModel.AllPersonal[0], false)">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/ServicePlan/_Priority1.cshtml");}
            </div>

Comment: yes you will get undefined try this `if:IsValidServicePlan.bind($data,$data, false)` . it should work . even this should work as you used in OP `IsValidServicePlan($data, false)` let me know

Comment: I tried both, but none is working super cool :(

Answer (score 1):

`Scope Issue` as you are trying to access `applicationView.ViewModel.AllPersonal[0]` in child level where it doesn't exists , tough it exists at `$parent` & `root` level .

You can cut short you binding in view using `$data` which refers to `current context` rather going with a broader way `($parent.applicationView.ViewModel.AllPersonal[0])` in view

**view:**

```
<div class="section-wrap break" id="ServicePlan_PrioritySection" data-bind="foreach:applicationView.ViewModel.AllPersonal">
<div data-bind="if:IsValidServicePlan($data,false)">
 @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/ServicePlan/_Priority1.cshtml");}
</div>
```

As a proper altenative you use `.bind` or `function` syntax in your view (as mentioned in comments)